# Stubbing static methods in MSpec

Tags: testing, rspec, bdd, stub, mspec

I'm trying to test a class that utilizes a repository class that is interfaced with through static methods. The actually repository interacts with a database. I do not want to setup a database in Test, I only to make sure that the repository methods are called. In the RSpec world I would do something like `allow(NodeRepository).to receive(:create).and_return(true)`. Is there a similar feature in MSpec or some other .NET testing tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to stub static methods in. NET without extra testing tools like TypeMock Isolator. All freely available mocking tools on .NET use dynamic proxies that cannot hook into non-virtual methods (which static methods are).